# Why would wine sellers need to broach the cask?

Tags: wine, history

I don't know if wine merchants still broach the cask in 2021, but why would they? Aren't casks manufactured with a spigot that a seller can just turn on, as shown below? I embolded the phrase below.

> #### broker [14]

> *Broker* has no connection with the
> past tense of *break*. It comes from Anglo-
> Norman *brocour* ‘small trader’, but its ultimate
> origin is not clear. A variant Anglo-Norman
> form *abrocour* has fuelled speculation as to a
> link with Spanish *alboroque* ‘sealing of a
> bargain’ and Portuguese *alborcar* ‘barter’,
> which are presumably of Arabic origin (the *al-* representing
> the Arabic definite article); but
> other etymologists have sought to link the word
> with *broach*, as if the underlying sense were
> **‘someone who sells wine from [that is, by
> broaching] the cask’**, and hence any ‘retailer’.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 77 Left column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that during aging, spigots aren’t inserted into the casks. I’m guessing that plugs are more reliable, allow tighter storage and are cheaper.

Comment: And a spigot would be a nightmare during transport.